# Apache's FileHandler saves unicode escapes instead of special chars

Tags: java, apache, configuration-files, unicode-escapes

I've been using Apache Commons Configuration2 to manage property files. The problem is, when saving the configurations to a file, **the special characters are replaced with their Java's source code**; as in `a=Rumänien -> a=Rum\u00E4nien`.

**Is there any way to avoid this?** Preferably using FileHandlers or similar Writers/Streams, as I'm not being able to use the Builder provided by Apache.

The reading is correctly performed. If I set a breakpoint I can see the correct value stored but, as soon as I want to persist the configuration, I get that kind of result.

Here's a MCVE, please note that you need to link the following Apache libraries:

- [Configuration2](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/)
- [Logging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/)
- [Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

  ```
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
      final String inputPath = "C:\\yourFullPath\\properties_in.cfg";
      final String outputPath = "C:\\yourFullPath\\properties_out.cfg";

      final PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration();

      try {
          // Load the config
          final FileHandler inputHandler = new FileHandler(config);
          inputHandler.setEncoding("UTF-8");
          inputHandler.setPath(inputPath);

          inputHandler.load();

          // Save the config in a different file
          final FileHandler outputHandler = new FileHandler(config);
          outputHandler.setEncoding("UTF-8");
          outputHandler.setPath(outputPath);

          outputHandler.save();
      } catch (final Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

The content of `properties_in.cfg` before and after running the code is `a=Rumänien`.

`properties_out.cfg` doesn't exist before running the code, and after doing it its content is `a=Rum\u00E4nien`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is, the strict definition for Java's property files requires them to be in `ISO-8859-1` encoding, and all Unicode characters not in it will be encoded with the `\uXXXX` escapes. So **technically** speaking everything works as specified.

If the library allows it (maybe with a [custom writer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html)), you could hack it to write UTF-8 and not perform the escapes.